# Join the last inserted data from a table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, zend-db

I have the following query using zend-db.

```
$select = $db->select()->from('assignment',array('assignment.id','form_type','assignment.no_of_files'))
        ->join('assignment_insurance','assignment_insurance.assignment_id = assignment.id',array('assignment_insurance.assignment_id','insurance_company_id','insurance_claim_number'))
        ->join('insurance','insurance.id = assignment_insurance.insurance_company_id',array('company'))
        ->join('assignment_insured_or_claimant','assignment_insured_or_claimant.assignment_id = assignment.id',array('first_name','last_name'))
        ->join('assignment_appraiser','assignment_appraiser.assignment_id = assignment.id',array('appraiser_id','next_status_date'))
        ->join('appraiser','appraiser.id = assignment_appraiser.appraiser_id',array('first_name as appraiser_first_name','last_name as appraiser_last_name'))
```

This query is working fine but i want to join the last data inserted from the table called status. The query of the status table that I want to join is something like,

```
SELECT * FROM `assignment_status` 
WHERE id=(the_assignment_id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

How can I do so? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Knowing nothing about zend, if it was me, I'd just construct a VIEW and select from that.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it. Thanks for the reply. :)                     
`->joinInner('assignment_status', 'assignment_status.assignment_id = assignment.id AND assignment_status.id = (SELECT id from assignment_status where assignment_id = assignment.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)',array('status','status_added_date','status_action'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i fixed it.

```
->joinInner('assignment_status', 'assignment_status.assignment_id = assignment.id AND assignment_status.id = (SELECT id from assignment_status where assignment_id = assignment.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)',array('status','status_added_date','status_action'))
```